# How to offset ol.style.Circle or ol.style.RegularShape?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

It is possible to define an offset for `ol.style.Text` instances (`offsetX` and `offsetY` properties) and define a custom anchor for `ol.style.Icon` instances. This functionality is not present neither in `ol.style.Circle` nor `ol.style.RegularShape`.

I need to draw my features as four shapes (triangles, circles, ...) with proper offsets so that they won't overlap and will be rendered completely.

E.g. `x` is the true coordinate of a feature and the four `O`s are four circles of different colors. Each represents a value of an attribute and I need to color them dynamically depending on the value.

```
O O
 x
O O
```

What is the best way to implement offsets? Is it possible to extend existing prototypes in some future-proof way? Or should I write my own style from scratch (I'd like to reuse as much of existing OL-3 code as possible)? Or is it better to use four `ol.style.Icon`s with different anchors?

Comment: 7 years and it's still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The most future proof way would be to contribute this improvement to OpenLayers. It should be quite easy to implement - the `anchor` option could be exposes more or less the same way it is done in `ol.style.Icon`.

To get started with contributing to OpenLayers 3, I'd recommend to read https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md.